# Creating an instance of API service in ES2015

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm primarily a C# developer with limited experience in JavaScript/EcmaScript and trying to understand the right way to create an instance of an API service that I can reuse in my functions.

The app I'm working on is a React app and the API service I'm trying to consume is Google Places. I created an external file for all Google Places related functions so that they're reusable. Here's the function I have in that file that will make the API call to get some suggestions from Google.

```
export const googleCall = (keyword) => {
    const googlePlacesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    googlePlacesAutocomplete.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, callback);
}
```

It makes no sense to keep "new"ing google.maps.places.AutocompleteService() every time a new keystroke comes into this function.

One option I can think of is that in my React app -- say in ComponentWillMount --- I can create an instance of this service and then pass it into this function along with the keyword but that seems a bit cumbersome. That would look something like this:

```
export const googleCall = (googleService, keyword) => {
    googleService.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, callback);
}
```

I think a better way would be to make sure the googleCall() function can access what's in the state i.e. in my redux store. In other words, I could create an instance of the googleService in a ComponentWillMount function and place it in my redux store. Just not sure how I can have this function access what's in my state.

Or, more generally speaking, in ES -- in particular in ES2015 -- how do I create an instance of this service that my googleCall function can access every time I call it without having to create a new instance of the service? I'm just not sure how this is done in ES where we create an instance of something and keep it in memory for subsequent calls.

UPDATE:

In my React component, I simply get the googleCall function like this:

```
import {googleCall} from '../googlePlacesFunctions';
```

Comment: Same way you do it in C#; use a variable? This sounds like more of a question of how to do this in React. You may want to emphasize that in the title and text.

Comment: Just use the singleton pattern.

Comment: use a private var in your module: `var googlePlacesAutocomplete; export const googleCall = (keyword) => {
    if(!googlePlacesAutocomplete) googlePlacesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    googlePlacesAutocomplete.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, callback);
}`

Comment: @Thomas seems like overkill to me. if the service constructor needed an argument form the function call then maybe, but may as well just instantiate it when the app loads.

Comment: @azium, I'm just lazy-loading the instance at first use. Not that complicated. And I don't think adding one `if` is overkill; but it's up to Sam to implement it the one way or the other. If the service constructor needed an argument form the function call then you'd need to consider a few things when caching these instances, but that's off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused by your question. Why not just?

```
// api.js

const googlePlacesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

export const googleCall = (keyword, callback) => {
  googlePlacesAutocomplete.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, callback);
}
```

That way you're not passing things around anywhere and you're not creating more than one instance of `AutocompleteService`

Comment: As I said, my knowledge of JS/ES is limited so I'm sure my question is pretty rudimentary. I do import the googleCall() function in my React component -- see the update in original post -- so I wasn't sure if if googlePlacesAutocomplete would be available to the googleCall() function if I were to declare and instantiate it in the external file. Looks like you're "importing" the api.js which I assume would include some Google Places API libraries.

Comment: @Sam, look up the concept of *closures* in JS. It's one of the most important features to understand

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the heads up. I just read up on it and l think what you're saying is that even though googlePlacesAutocomplete is out of scope as far as the React component is concerned, because I'm importing googleCall() into my component and the googleCall() needs the service, the instance of googlePlacesAutocomplete will be created and kept it in scope -- due to closure concept in JS.

Comment: @Sam i wrote `api.js` at the top of the file to say the following contents belong to the file named `api.js`. I haven't written any imports there. So sounds like you're on the right track. the function `googleCall` has access to the service because it was created inside the same module, but only things in that module have access to it.